# Is this a Cauchy random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent $n(0,1)$ random variables.
How do I find $P(X^2+Y^2\leq 1)$ and $P(X^2\leq 1)$, after verifying that $X^2$ is distributed $\chi_{1}^{2}$?

My attempt:

$$P(X^2+Y^2\leq 1)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\sqrt{1-y^2} \frac{1}{2\pi} e^\frac{-x^2+y^2}{2} dxdy $$

How do I proceed from it?

Comment: Should your title be "Is this a **chi-squared** random variable?"?

Comment: $X^2 \sim CHISQ(1), P(X^2 < 1) = P(-1 < X < 1) =  0.6826895$ from R where `pchis` and `pnorm` are CDFs or the 2 relevant dist'ns: code `pchisq(1, 1)` and `diff(pnorm(c(-1,1)))` both return 0.6826895. Also $Q=X^2 + Y^2 \sim CHISQ(2),$ perhaps most easily proved using MGFs. $P(Q \le 1) $ can be found in R from `pchisq(1, 2)`, which returns 0.3934693.

Comment: You might get an aprx value for $P(Q \le 1)$ from looking at a printed table of the chi-sq dist'n with DF=2. Not all printed tables give enough detail to be helpful, but some do. // But if you haven't started using R, you can get it for free and with very little trouble online. Start by learning how the probability functions work: `pnorm`, `dbinom`, `runif`, etc. Just use the bits of R that are immediately helpful to you. There is good user-group help online. You'll _never_ learn all of it. If you did, you'd be the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of your question appears to be: "How do I show that if $X \sim N(0, 1)$, then $X^2 \sim \chi^2(1)$?"

Here's the gist: Let $f(x), F(x)$ be the density and cdf of a standard normal variable, respectively. (Note that $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$, but that $F(x)$ doesn't have a clean closed-form expression.) We want to know more about the variable $U = X^2$, so call *its* density and cdf by $g(x)$ and $G(x)$, respectively.

First, note that for $x > 0$,
\begin{align*}G(x) &= \mathbb P(U \leq x) \\ &= \mathbb P(X^2 \leq x) \\ &= \mathbb P(-\sqrt x \leq X \leq \sqrt x) \\  &= F(\sqrt x) - F(-\sqrt x).
\end{align*}
It follows that
\begin{align*}
  g(x) &= G'(x) \\ &= \frac{\textrm d}{\textrm d x} [F(\sqrt x) - F(-\sqrt x)] \\
&= f(\sqrt x) \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt x} + f(-\sqrt x) \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt x}
\end{align*}
for all $x > 0$, and if you evaluate that, it happens to be exactly the density of a $\chi^2$ variable with 1 df.

There are lots of details in the steps above, but I wasn't sure about your background in the material, so let me know if there are steps that need clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X,Y\sim\ N(0,1)$, then $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are chi-squared with 1 degree of freedom each.

Since $X^2,Y^2\sim\chi^2(1)$ and they are independent, then $X^2+Y^2\sim\chi^2(2)$.

So to compute those probabilities, use a chi-squared density (or R).

Comment: How do I find $P(X^2\leq 1)$, after verifying that $X^2$ is distributed $\chi_{1}^{2}$?

Comment: Using a chi-squared density with 1 degree of freedom.  The density is $f_{X^2}(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2)2^{1/2}}x^{-1/2}e^{-x/2}$.  Or if you are using r, `pchisq(1,1)`

Comment: But how do I show that $X^2$ is distributed $\chi_{1}^{2}$?